# An algebra is a vector space

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field. If I have $A$ is a finite-dimensional $F$-algebra, then can I conclude that $A$ is a finite-dimensional over $F$?

Comment: If I am not wrong, it means that there are $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in A$ such that $A=F[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]$.

Comment: If it means this: consider the polynomial ring in one variable for a counterexample.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to understand the proof of lemma 1.14 of this lecture notes http://toknotes.mimuw.edu.pl/sem7/files/Maszczyk_gs.pdf According to his proof, I understand he used the fact as if my question is true.

Comment: In that context, yes, means the algebra is a finite dimensional vector space. You cannot really conclude it, as it is the definition.

Comment: I am so sorry. Apparently, I have misunderstood. By the way, as in his proof, I cannot see where we use the fact that $\mathbb{E}$ is an integral domain.

Comment: It is used when it says "we can divide by the monomial of the lowest degree"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A finite-dimensional $F$-algebra is an $F$-algebra which finite dimensional as a vector space over $F$. For instance, a finite extension of $F$ or $\mathcal M_n(F)$, the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficient in $F$, of the $\mathbf R$-algebra $\mathbf H$   of quaternions.